# How can I determine the window controlled by an instance of NSWindowController ?

Tags: appkit, nswindowcontroller

How can I determine the window controlled by an instance of NSWindowController ? According to Apple's docs, sending the controller the 'window' accessor message returns  "The window owned by the receiver."  But when I use it on an instance loaded from a NIB via initWithWindowNibPath:owner: it always returns 0.

I've searched unsuccessfully through Apple's AppKit docs for another message that might work better. (It's possible that a function that returns the content _view for the window in question would also work, since my ultimate goal is to be able to access the contained Views via their Tag fields.)

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of this window accessor? If so, is there a method that will allow me to determine the actual window controlled by my NSController instance?

thanks

Comment: `NSWindowController` is not a subclass of `NSController`. Is the windowcontroller nil or released?

Comment: The windowcontroller is neither nil nor released. It works exactly as expected except for this not being abe to determine the owned window.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to the question?